# How do I use a Dojo tap.hold gesture

Tags: javascript, mobile, dojo, dom-events

I need to have a Javascript press and hold (long-press) event attached to a dom element. The example on Dojo's site (https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/gesture.html#dojox-gesture) doesn't work at all, and I haven't found any working example.

```
define(["dojo/on", "dojox/gesture/tap"], function(on, tap){
 var node = document.getElementById("box");
 on(node, tap.hold, function(e){ alert('held') });
});
```

Associated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8Tp6/1/

I don't mind doing this in straight Javascript, if the Dojo option doesn't work out, but I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the gesture or the event, but you using `define()`. `define()` should only be used when defining modules (as the name explains). When you load such a file, it will actually don't do anything. It won't load the modules and it won't execute the callbacks. The only way to make the callback run is when you call it from a `require()`.

Your main Dojo file should always use `require()`. So to your code: replace `define()` with `require()` and it will work like a charm.

Code:

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojox/gesture/tap"], function(on, tap){
 var node = document.getElementById("box");
 on(node, tap.hold, function(e){ alert('held') });
});
```

I also updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/L8Tp6/2/).

Comment: Interesting that their documentation shows it the way I was using it. And in my case, I actually was using it in a module with several other loaded modules. But my fiddle was pretty much a direct copy of their documentation. Thanks for reorienting me in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with **DojoX** modules is that the documentation usually isn't that good, as you can see here. While it's technically correct (if you use it in a module), it's confusing without a proper context, like this example.

Answer (score 0):

To Detect hold end:

```
on(node, tap.hold, function(e){
    e.target.ontouchend = function(){
        console.log('You quit holding');
    }
});
```